# Python code successfully writes data to JSON but does not loop back to fishing function

Tags: python, json, nextcord

I've been working on this a few days now but can't seem to find an answer.

I'm making a fish catching bot using Nextcord and what I want the code to do is, if the user is already written in the JSON, to catch fish, if they are not, then write them down in the JSON, then catch fish.

The problem is, with the way the code is structured now, it successfully writes myself down correctly. However, it fails to loop back around and catch fish.

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
import random
from data import fish_types
import time
from os import path
import json

TESTING_GUILD_ID = sensitive data  # Replace with your guild ID

bot = commands.Bot()
score_file = r'sensitive data'


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')

@bot.slash_command(description="Introduction and a list of available commands.", guild_ids=[TESTING_GUILD_ID])
async def help(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    await interaction.send("Hello, I'm Bebu-Bot! My currently available commands are: help, fish, and fishscore")

@bot.slash_command(description="Go fishing!", guild_ids=[TESTING_GUILD_ID])
async def fish(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    if str(interaction.user) in score_file:
        caught_fish = random.randint(0, 1000)
        await interaction.send("You cast your line...")
        time.sleep(3)
        if caught_fish <= 250:
            await interaction.send("You caught: " + str(fish_types[0]))
        elif caught_fish <= 400:
            await interaction.send("You caught: " + str(fish_types[1]))
        elif caught_fish <= 700:
            await interaction.send("You caught: " + str(fish_types[2]))
        elif caught_fish <= 800:
            await interaction.send("You caught: " + str(fish_types[3]))
        elif caught_fish <= 850:
            await interaction.send("You caught: " + str(fish_types[4]))
        elif caught_fish <= 925:
            await interaction.send("You caught: " + str(fish_types[5]))
        elif caught_fish <= 975:
            await interaction.send("You caught: " + str(fish_types[6]))
        else:
            await interaction.send("You caught: " + str(fish_types[7]))
    if str(interaction.user) not in score_file:
        def write_score(data, filename=score_file):
            with open (filename, "w") as f:
                json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
        with open(score_file) as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            temp = data["usernames"]
            y = {"name": str(interaction.user), "score": 0}
            temp.append(y)
            write_score(data)
            json_file.close()
            return
    


#@bot.slash_command(description="Show user's fishing score!", guild_ids=[TESTING_GUILD_ID])
#async def fishscore(interaction: nextcord.Interaction):








bot.run('sensitive data')
```

I've tried switching both if statements around, using if and else instead and using a for loop, all work the same except the for loop just looping infinitely of course. I'm not sure what else to do, and if you have any tips I'd gladly appreciate them!